# Copy constructor of a class with a const vector member

Tags: c++, constants, copy-constructor

I have the class `OpenTable` in my code:

```
class OpenTable : public BaseAction {
public:
    OpenTable(int id, std::vector<Customer *> &customersList);
    OpenTable(const OpenTable& other);
private:
    const int tableId;
    const std::vector<Customer *> customers;
};
```

I need to implement a copy constructor for this class (I know it's probably a bad design, but I was instructed to do so). I ran into a problem when trying to deep copy the const vector `customers`.

I tried the following:

```
OpenTable::OpenTable(const OpenTable& other): tableId(other.tableId)
{
    for(std::vector<Customer*>::const_iterator i=other.customers.begin(); i!=other.customers.end(); i++) {
         customers.push_back((*i)->copy()); // copy returns a Customer*
    }
```

But clearly it doesn't compile, probably because the vector is `const`, thus I can't add elements to it.

I get the following error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back 
[with _Tp=Customer *, _Alloc=std::allocator<Customer *>]" matches the 
argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a 
match) -- argument types are: (Customer *) -- object type is: const 
std::vector<Customer *, std::allocator<Customer *>>
```

Note: In the parameterized constructor I simply shallow copied because I could. This won't work for the copy constructor though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `Customer` a polymorphic base class? If not, why do you need pointers? And if you need pointers, have you thought about the *ownership* semantics and perhaps share the ownership of the `Customer` objects with a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)?

Comment: `const` data members are almost never worth the trouble.

Comment: are the customers owned by the class? Are shared resources? Or just observing pointers. And the most important question: **What should the copy constructor do?**

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The question you made this a dupe of doesn't contain an answer for when deep copying is needed to initialize the constant member.

Comment: Create a helper function (which can be `private` and `static` member of your class if you want to limit access to it) that accepts a `const std::vector<Customer *>` and returns a `std::vector<Customer *>` that is a deep copy.   Then, in the initialiser list of your constructor, use it to initialise your private member.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is a class derived from another (which is pure virtual), it was given to me as is (meaning I'm not allowed to delete members, only add new ones)

Comment: By the way, how do you do it with the other constructor? Do you make a deep copy of the vector *before* you construct the `OpenTable` object?

Comment: @Peter It sounds like a good solution, however isn't it bad to call class methods from the constructor? Or is it ok because it's a static function (and belongs to the class rather than the object)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Stated in the question, in the parametrized constructor I can shallow copy and it's working as intended. Tried to keep it short and not post the entire code here, sorry.

Comment: @bolov Deep copy the pointers in the vector customers.

Comment: Anyway thanks all, @peter post the answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You should remove the duplicate tag, it's misleading and incorrect.

Comment: @BarakB it's fine to call a non-virtual member that doesn't depend on (not-yet-initialised) member data. A `static` member easily meets those criteria

Comment: Yeah, okay.   My previous comment isn't really a full answer, but I'll turn it into one shortly.

Comment: As an aside, changing the pointers to `std::unique_ptr<Customer>` will make it *so much easier* to provide exception guarantees for your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to create a helper function  that accepts a `const std::vector<Customer *>` and returns a `std::vector<Customer *>` that is a deep copy of the argument. Then, in the initialiser list of your constructor, use that function to initialise your private member.

Optionally, that helper function can be a `private` and `static` member of your class if you want to limit access to it.   That is acceptable in a constructor or its initialiser list, since a `static` member function does not rely on non-static members of class being initialised, so does not rely on the constructor having completed.

If a problem occurs in the helper function making the deep copy, the helper function will need to clean up appropriately (e.g. if construction of one of the `Customer` objects fails, any successfully constructed objects will need to be released to avoid a memory leak).

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need something like [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) to do the copying as part of the member initialiser.

```
auto copy_iter(auto iter)
{
    return boost::make_transform_iterator(iter, [](Customer * c){ return c->copy(); });
}

OpenTable::OpenTable(const OpenTable& other)
 : tableId(other.tableId),
   customers(copy_iter(other.customers.begin()), copy_iter(other.customers.end()))
{}
```

or alternately

```
OpenTable::OpenTable(const OpenTable& other)
 : tableId(other.tableId),
   customers(boost::copy_range<std::vector<Customer *>>(other.customers | boost::adaptors::transformed([](Customer * c){ return c->copy(); })))
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use const class memebers? You can nothing do with them. Make the public access funtions read only instead.

```
std::vector<Customers *> const getCustumers() const { return customers;}
int const getTableId() const { return tableId; }
```

This will give you a read only vector of customers or a table id that can't be modifyed. Than the copy constuctor is no problem.